# Как в WordPress создать редактор такого типа?

Tags: wordpress

Как в WordPress создать редактор такого типа?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ вернёт "старый" редактор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать метабокс и вывести редактор с помощью ф-ции `wp_editor()` https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_editor

Либо можете использовать плагин Advanced Custom Field и создать поле через GUI.

Comment: Использую  Advanced Custom Field, можете подсказать более детально как через поле GUI сделать?

Comment: Укажите тип поля "Редактор WordPress"

Comment: https://imgur.com/3ZxcgTF - а как добавить там например жирный текст?

Comment: У поля есть настройки "Панель инструментов" укажите full

Comment: Еще одно, 
https://imgur.com/C0yP8iL - в редакторе
https://imgur.com/qx9THsI - в коде
Можно ли сделать чтобы оно так и работало?

Comment: Нет, используйте разные поля для этого. Сделайте 2 поля одно текстовое для заголовка и остальное для контента. Так же не используйте сокращение открытия php кода